# How do you edit MP3 tags in Java (ID3)?

Tags: java, metadata, mp3, id3, id3-tag

Lately, I've been trying to write a program that can change the ID3 tags of an mp3 file. I managed to write code to get those tags quite easily, but I have no idea how to write code to modify the tags. I assumed that there may be no easy solution, so I decided to try out some libraries. It may be my fault, but none of them work..

Anyway, my question is: how do I write my own code to modify ID3 tags? If it's not that easy, are there any libraries you can recommend?

Comment: This question should have been closed.  It is both "too broad" - *"how do I write my own code to modify ID3 tags?"* and a request for a recommendation.

Comment: The problem is not that it was not asked well.  The problem is that it is a request for a recommendation.  And requests for recommendations are **explicitly** off-topic.  It doesn't matter that many users would *like* StackOverflow to be a recommendations site.  It isn't, and the "what not to ask" page is very clear about it.

Comment: If you (or anyone else) would like request a recommendation for a Java library  that can modify id3 tags, a more appropriate place to ask would be https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not an old question like this.  AFAIK.

Comment: Questions about the appropriate use of bonuses, recommendation questions, migration and so on belong on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the library [jAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). Below is an example that writes a custom tag (TXXX) to an audio file:

```java
/**
 * This will write a custom ID3 tag (TXXX).
 * This works only with MP3 files (Flac with ID3-Tag not tested).
 * @param description The description of the custom tag i.e. "catalognr"
 * There can only be one custom TXXX tag with that description in one MP3 file
 * @param text The actual text to be written into the new tag field
 * @return True if the tag has been properly written, false otherwise
 */

public boolean setCustomTag(AudioFile audioFile, String description, String text){
    FrameBodyTXXX txxxBody = new FrameBodyTXXX();
    txxxBody.setDescription(description);
    txxxBody.setText(text);

    // Get the tag from the audio file
    // If there is no ID3Tag create an ID3v2.3 tag
    Tag tag = audioFile.getTagOrCreateAndSetDefault();
    // If there is only a ID3v1 tag, copy data into new ID3v2.3 tag
    if(!(tag instanceof ID3v23Tag || tag instanceof ID3v24Tag)){
        Tag newTagV23 = null;
        if(tag instanceof ID3v1Tag){
            newTagV23 = new ID3v23Tag((ID3v1Tag)audioFile.getTag()); // Copy old tag data               
        }
        if(tag instanceof ID3v22Tag){
            newTagV23 = new ID3v23Tag((ID3v11Tag)audioFile.getTag()); // Copy old tag data              
        }           
        audioFile.setTag(newTagV23);
    }

    AbstractID3v2Frame frame = null;
    if(tag instanceof ID3v23Tag){
        frame = new ID3v23Frame("TXXX");
    }
    else if(tag instanceof ID3v24Tag){
        frame = new ID3v24Frame("TXXX");
    }

    frame.setBody(txxxBody);

    try {
        tag.addField(frame);
    } catch (FieldDataInvalidException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    try {
        audioFile.commit();
    } catch (CannotWriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way. I've been looking for an answer like this for ages. +100

Answer (score 2):

This library:

http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

provides a means of reading and writing id3 tags.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up coding a tag editor myself since I didn't want to use a library. It's for ID3v1 tags only.
[Full Code](https://github.com/nh7dev/ID3v1TagEditorJava/blob/master/src/dev.nh7.id3/ID3v1TagEditor.java)

[Here](https://id3.org/ID3v1)'s how it works:
[image]

So all you have to do is write 128 bytes to the end of the file. Starting with `TAG`, followed by 30 bytes for the title, 30 for the artist, etc. The genre list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ID3v1_Genres).

```
    public void writeID3v1Tags(File file, String title, String artist, String album, String year, String comment, int genreId) { throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();

        if (!hasID3v1Tag(channel)) {
            channel.position(channel.size());
            writeTag(channel, "TAG", 3);
        }

        writeTag(channel, title, 30);
        writeTag(channel, artist, 30);
        writeTag(channel, album, 30);
        writeTag(channel, year, 4);
        writeTag(channel, comment, 30);
        writeTag(channel, String.valueOf((char) genreId), 1);

        channel.close();
    }

    private void writeTag(FileChannel channel, String tagValue, int maxLength) throws IOException {
        int length = tagValue.length();
        if (length > maxLength) {
            tagValue = tagValue.substring(0, maxLength);
            length = tagValue.length();
        }

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(tagValue.getBytes());
        channel.write(byteBuffer);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxLength - length);
        channel.write(byteBuffer);
    }

    private boolean hasID3v1Tag(FileChannel channel) throws IOException {
        channel.position(channel.size() - 128);
        String prefix = readTag(channel, 3);
        return "TAG".equals(prefix);
    }
```

If you want more tags (like album cover, lyrics, and much more) you need to use ID3v2. It works basically the same but is a little bit more complex, more info under https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Comment: Added some explanation & code