# Copy file attributes to other files

Tags: java

with class Files
"copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)"
and 
CopyOption COPY ATTRIBUTES
mp3 tags are easily copied.

But how can I transfer mp3 tags from e.g. file1.mp3 to file2.mp3 without creating new files or moving files?

Background: I resized .mp3 files and want to transfer the tags of the old files to the new files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good recommendations for MP3/Sound libraries for java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86083/any-good-recommendations-for-mp3-sound-libraries-for-java)

Comment: MP3 attributes are stored in ID3 tags inside the MP3 file.  Files.copy() and Java's NIO2 API only works with file system attributes.

Comment: You say you have mp3 tags on a class file. I would like to know how you think that is possible.

Comment: I mean the tag "Rating WMP", that are stars you can rate a music file in Windows (7)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [Editing mp3 files in Java(ID3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031250/editing-mp3-files-in-javaid3)

You might also have luck with the [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The library [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) seems like it may fit the bill. See its readme for examples of reading and updating the various ID3-version tags.