# How to read/write ID3v2 tags with java?

Tags: java, mp3

I want to be able to read ID3v2 tags from mp3 files. I have found multiple frameworks which allow me to get the basic tags. But I would like to be able those in this [list](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/docs/mappings/). I don't care about backwards compatibility with IDv1.

I already had a look at [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) and [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic). I didn't find out how to use them for custom tags. Is this possible?

Comment: I've been using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360589/5645656) for four years and it's still working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to use the string identifier "TXXX", that's the main difference between "normal" and custom fields. I think the following code should be self-explanatory:

```
AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(File songFile) // try and catch

MP3File mp3 = (MP3File) audioFile;                    
AbstractID3v2Tag v2Tag = mp3.getID3v2Tag();          

// Since you've mentioned a list
List<TagField> tagList = v2Tag.getFields("TXXX")
```

That's one way to do it. The List has now all tags with the TXXX identifier. Now you can simply call toString() on every element in the list and you should get something along those lines:

```
Description="Play Count"; Text="1.000.000"
```

Comment: The method `getFields` does not exist?

Comment: Wow, you are right. Wonder why I did it this way back then? Maybe try to replace `AbstractID3v2Tag v2Tag = mp3.getID3v2Tag();` with `ID3v1Tag v1Tag = mp3.getID3v1Tag();`. I will take a closer look at it and edit my answer next weekend. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Just checking back in. Any luck?